# What's the maxium number of files a Unix folder can hold?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

What's the maxium number of files a Unix folder can hold?

I think it will be the same as the number of files.

Comment: A much better question might be: How many should I use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many

Comment: I'd love for my site url's to look like site.com/username/ and so on, but thinking that (if im lucky) get more than 2 million users that'd be more than 2 million folders, since I don't want to use a script such as PHP with a modrewrite i was looking at the other possibilitie of folders in a folder

Comment: Do yourself a favor and create subdirectories with a rewriting scheme.

Answer (score 21):

Varies per file system, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Comment: lol            !

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comparison_of_file_systems&diff=prev&oldid=266054153

Answer (score 18):

On all current Unix filesystems a directory can hold a practically *unlimited* number of files. Whereas "unlimited" is limited by diskspace and [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) - whatever runs out first.

With older file system designs ([ext2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2), [UFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System), [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus)) things tend to get slow if you have many files in a directory. Usually things start getting painful around 10,000 files. With newer filesystems ([ReiserFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReiserFS), [XFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS), [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS), [UFS2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System#Implementations)) you can have millions of files in a directory without seeing general performance bottlenecks.

But having so many files in a directory is not well tested and there are lots of tools which fail that. For example, periodic system maintenance scripts may barf on it.

I happily used a directory with several million files on UFS2 and had seen no problems until I wanted to delete the directory - that took several DAYS.

Answer (score 13):

It depends how many [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) the filesystem was created with.  Executing

```
df -i
```

will give you the number of free inodes.  This is the practical limit of how many files a filesystem and hence a directory can hold.

Comment: However, many filesystems have a limit of files per directory, regardless of the number of inodes free.

Comment: yes, but the question targeted UNIX filesystems and as far as I am aware all modern UNIX filesystems do not limit the number of files in a directory.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are thinking of storing a lot of files in one place, no?

Most modern Unix files systems can put **a lot** of files in one directory, but operations like following paths, listing files, etc. involve a linear search through the list of files and get slow if the list grows too large.

I seem to recall hearing that a couple of thousand is too many for most practical uses. The typically solution is to break the grouping up. That is,

```
/some/path/to/dir/a/
/some/path/to/dir/b/
...
/some/path/to/dir/z/
```

and store your files in the appropriate sub-directory according to a hash of their `basename`. Choose a convenient hash, the first character might do for simple cases.

---

Cristian Ciupitu writes in the comments that [XFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS), and possibly other very new file-systems, use `log(N)` searchable structures to hold directory contents, so this constraint is greatly [ameliorated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ameliorate).

Comment: Some modern filesystems, e.g. XFS don't involve a linear search. XFS's B-Tree technology enables it to go directly to the blocks and/or extents containing a file's location using sophisticated indices (from http://www.uoks.uj.edu.pl/resources/flugor/IRIX/xfs-whitepaper.html).

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that. Thanks. Will add to the text.

Comment: For ext3, you have to activate the "dir_index" feature, cf. tune2fs(8).

Answer (score 0):

`ext3` one of the most common linux filesystem formats gets really sluggish if you have around 20k + file in a directory. Regardless of how many it can hold, you should try to avoid having that many files in one directory.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment you left, I think you don't really care about how many files/folders your FS can host.

You should probably consider using ModRewrite and rewriting site.com/username to site.com/?user= or something of the kind and store all your data in a database. Creating one folder per user is generally not necessary (and not a good idea).

That said, each filesystem has limits, and `df` can tell you how many inodes are available on each partition of your system.